# Set my sitecontent to the right place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single paged website designed with Jquery and html. I've got a div called #site-content which holds all the "pages", and has a width of 4400px. Page 1 starts at left : 0px;, the second at left : -1100px, the third at left : -2200px, and the fourth at left : -3300px;, on the third page e.g. i get this :

```
<div id="site-content" style="left: -2200px;">
```

After refreshing the page, it starts again at left : 0px;.

Is there a way in which I can make sure that it starts again at left : -2200px;??

Code example would be really appriciated,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you mean after refresh you have page1 again and not page 3? Or you want to know how to set the left style attribute on a div?

Comment: after refresh if i was on page3 i want to get on page3 after refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use anchor-navigation.

This code should work, if url looks like: http://site.com/#1 or something like that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var anchor = window.location.hash; // not sure about correct getting anchor
  $("#site-content").animate({ left:(1100*anchor)+"px" }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can use any url, but you don't need slash after ".php" part : correct url - site.com/index.php#1